# How to see the Status messages in DUnit GUI from all the test cases at once?

Tags: delphi, delphi-2010, status, dunit

You can use `TAbstractTest.Status` procedure to show some debug messages in DUnit GUI during your tests.

But when I run the group of tests, I can see only the status messages from the last executed test. Can I see the complete log somehow, without selecting each single test to run?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The DUnit source code uses a IStatusListener interface and a public method

```
procedure TAbstractTest.SetStatusListener(Listener: IStatusListener);
```

which could be overriden to use a new implementation in your test classes. I have not tried it but it could be the cleanest solution.

Answer (score 3):

I have used Status() method which will output the value when a failure occurs:

```
procedure Test.TestGetStringListQueryValuesException;
var
  ReturnValue: TList<String>;
  item: String;
begin
  ReturnValue := FTest.GetStringListQueryValues;
  try
    for item in ReturnValue do
    begin
      Status('Value Processed: ' + item);
      CheckTrue(Pos('B', item) > 0, 'Wrong Value, Expected Item containing ''B'' but found: ' + item);
    end;
  finally
    ReturnValue.Free;
  end;
end;
```

The result of that is somethig like this:

```
TestGetIntegerListQueryValuesException: ETestFailure
at  $0050B842
Wrong Value, Expected > 50 and < 60 but found: 61, expected: <True> but was: <False>

Status Messages
Value Processed: 52
Value Processed: 54
Value Processed: 55
Value Processed: 58
Value Processed: 59
Value Processed: 61
```

It is really useful to identify what went wrong during the test.
I haven't tried the SetStatusListener() but I think it should be the correct way if we want to show logging when a test has succeeded.

I would like to mimic the same behaviour as per Nunit where you can log customised messages on the output section.

Any better ideas?

Answer (score 0):

First write a new procedure

```
   procedure Log(text: string);
   begin
      LogStringList.Add(text);
      Status(text);
   end;
```

the replace all `status()` to `Log()`. And create a new test at the end of al tests

```
   procedure TestXXX.ShowLog;
   begin
      Status(LogStringList.Text);
      LogStringList.Clear;
   end;
```

you have to create `LogStringList: TStringList` in the initialization block of your test-unit.